# Valid character validation

Tags: python, validation

I have tried fixing this code i dont understand why it inst working it is meant to validate that a number has 4 charecters only numbers and no repeats.

```
    ValidChr =("0123456789",)
    for i in range(num):
        if num.count(i)!= 1:
            return "False"
        if i != ValidChr:
            return "False"
    if length(num) != 4:
        return "False"
    return "True"
print (Validate(1435))
```

Comment: `if i not in ValidChr`

Answer (score 0):

This returns the correct results:

```
def Validate(num):
    ValidChr =('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0')
    for i in enumerate(num):
        if i[1] not in ValidChr:
            return "False"
    if len(set(str(num))) < len(str(num)) or len(num) != 4:
            return "False"
    return "True"
print(Validate("1435"))
print(Validate("1111"))
print(Validate("12345"))
```

Output:

```
True
False
False
```